# Grouping Individual Tag Data Into Associated Elements In Table Rows Tibco Spotfire

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I have individual tag data in Spotfire for valves that I would like to display in a table.

The issue is that the data is coming from Pi in the form individual Tag data for each of the 300 valves (1200 Tags) like this:

```
Valve_In_Auto
Valve_Description
Valve_Manual_Time
Valve_Operator_Comment
```

With data like this:

```
Valve1_In_Auto = False
Valve1_Description = Sump Pump 36 Valve 1 
Valve1_In_Manual_Time = 300
Valve1_Operator_Comments = "Valve sticky"

Valve2_In_Auto = True
Valve2_Description = Sump Pump 36 Valve 2 
Valve2_Operation_Time = 0
Valve2_Operator_Comments = ""
```

What I am trying to achieve is to create a table row for every valve (300) grouped by the valve name like this:

```
Valve Name   In Auto       Description         Manual Time     Comment
  Valve_1     FALSE     Sump Pump 36 Valve 1        30       Valve sticky
  Valve_2     TRUE      Sump Pump 36 Valve 2         0            -
```

I was thinking to the best way to associate the individual tag data for each valve and to create the extra column "Valve Name" would be to use the substring ie "Valve1", "Valve2" ect but I am new to spotfire and not sure if this is the best way to do it or if this even possible.

Or is it possible to split into arrays and then convert that to a table?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is your question, "what is the best way to get my data into Spotfire?" I'm having trouble understanding what you'd like to accomplish

Comment: Spotfire is not an ETL tool. Spotfire is an analytics/reporting tool. What you are trying to do is read data into Spotfire that is poorly formatted, and completely change its structure with python in Spotfire? You would be much better off fixing this before it got to Spotfire, either with some SQL coding or through the use of an actual ETL tool.

Comment: Thanks the data is already in Spotfire. Unfortunately the PI connectors for Spotfire  (Osisoft Pi Historian) do not allow for the data to be modified before being sent and the data is stored this way at the control system level. So as much as it twould be better I am trying to find a way to modify it in Spotfire,